# Is this normed vector space complete?

Tags: banach-spaces, normed-spaces, cauchy-sequences

The normed vector space in question is $(C^{1}[0,1],\Vert \cdot \Vert _c )$ where $\| f \| _c := \lvert f(1) \rvert + \lVert f' \rVert _{1}$

For the first part of the question I had to work out whether or not $\| \cdot \| _c $ was a norm, which I believe it is. The second part was to work out which norms made the above vector space a complete normed space (there were norms indexed with $a$ and $b$ but this is the one I really need help with) i.e is $(C^{1}[0,1],\| \cdot \| _c )$ complete?

I feel as though it isn't complete, my intuition is that simply evaluating $f(x)$ at $1$ isn't enough 'information' or perhaps it's better to say that it's not restrictive enough? However, I'm really bad at giving counterexamples in these types of questions, I was thinking of constructing a Cauchy sequence $(f_n)$ that converges to a  continuous function with a discontinuous derivative and set $f_n(1)=0$ which would simplify things.

Any ideas of a counterexample? or maybe an explanation as to why it maybe complete? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: Do you know any example of a Cauchy sequence in $(C[0,1],\|\cdot\|_1)$ that does not converge? By means of integration you might be able to turn this into an example of a Cauchy sequence in $(C^1[0,1],\|\cdot\|_c)$ that does not converge.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I do actually have such an example in my lecture notes. A sequence of functions where identically $0$ for $x \in [0,1/2]$ then a straight line for $x \in [1/2,1/2 +1/n]$ then identically $1$ for the rest of domain. This converge to a step function, so are you saying find a function who's derivative behaves like this?

Comment: Of course these functions You describe are not in $C^1([0,1])$. Do You know mollifiers?@Displayname

Comment: @Displayname That is exactly what I was aiming at. With the fundamental theorem of calculus you should be able to finish.

Comment: okay thanks, yeah I can probably finish this proof off now. @PeterMelech I know but the functions are in $C([0,1])$ and so if I integrate them piecewise, then their integrals will be in $C^1([0,1])$? And no I've never heard of mollifiers

Comment: Not sure if this works, if You take the functions You describe You'll get something like $$f(x)=\begin{cases}C_1,0\leq x\leq \frac{1}{2}\\ \frac{n}{2}x^2-\frac{n}{2}x+C_2,\frac{1}{2}\leq x\leq \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}\\x+C_3,\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n}\leq x\leq 1\end{cases}$$ and You are right, these are in $C^1$

Comment: for appropriate constants

Comment: yeah looks good, I'll explicitly state the constants in my proof so the continuity is clearly shown

Comment: For Your purpose the choice $C_3=0$ and thus $C_2(n)=1-\frac{n}{2}(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n})^2+\frac{n}{2}(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{n})$ and $C_1=\frac{1}{8}-\frac{n}{4}+C_2(n)$ would be good, because then $|f_n(1)-f_m(1)|=0$ and You are hopefully on the way to Your Cauchyseries

Comment: I'm sorry Cauchy-sequence